# Reload a field from the controller.php

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have a logic hook that changes a field's value, but in order to see the change I need to refresh the whole page... I want it to refresh the field in real time.

So I'm trying to accomplish something like this(https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/21178-refresh-sub-panel-values-when-another-sub-panel-is-updated#75194)

But instead of reloading a whole subpanel through the controller.php I'm trying to find a way to refresh a single field.

Can anyone advise what method needs to be used to reload a field?

**For example to reload a subpanel it's**

**

> **showSubPanel('SUBPANEL_NAME',null,true);**

**

But what is the JS method that reload a single field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any built-in functions in suiteCRM that do it, spent a lot of time going through the chrome debugger, but nothing worked.

Here's a video that explains what's happening and the actual code example
https://youtu.be/ebuwWZoSYCk

You need to get the new status from the back-end then update the field inside the controller.php with:

```
document.querySelector('div[type="enum"][field="$field_to_update"]').innerHTML = "$inventory_status_c";
```

The whole controller.php file example is here, it all makes sense if you watch the 5 minute video:

```
class un_inventoryController extends SugarController {

    /**
     *
     */
    function action_SubPanelViewer() {



    require_once 'include/SubPanel/SubPanelViewer.php';


// only if this is creation of new sale under accounts, refresh the screen so the salerow subpanel will be refreshed too
if ( array_key_exists('module', $_REQUEST) && array_key_exists('subpanel', $_REQUEST) && array_key_exists('action', $_REQUEST) &&
$_REQUEST['module'] == 'un_inventory' && $_REQUEST['subpanel'] == "un_inventory_leads_1" && $_REQUEST['action'] == "SubPanelViewer") {


    write_to_log(array("request" => $_REQUEST), "all conditions filled, custom controller called", true);

    // Get the ID of the inventory unit so we can fetch the new status_c field and update the field right away (otherwise we'll have to refresh the page

    $inventory = BeanFactory::getBean($_REQUEST["module"], $_REQUEST["record"]);
    $inventory_status_c = ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $inventory->status_c));
    $field_to_update = "status_c";

    $js=<<<EOQ
<script>

    // Update the status
    $( document ).ready(function() { 

        document.querySelector('div[type="enum"][field="$field_to_update"]').innerHTML = "$inventory_status_c";

    });


</script>
EOQ;

    echo $js;


    }

}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To refresh a detailView through a logic hook, you can use an easy "hack".

In your logic_hook, place the following js code as your last "echo" before your return or exit:

```
echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";
```

Simple but effective.

Comment: Thank you Lucas, I read somewhere that it's not always 100% consistent across devices/browsers, but may be i'm wrong

Comment: It's a very standard js code. It will work anywhere, provided SuiteCRM "gets" something from the logic_hook to the screen.

Comment: "will work anywhere" and JS rarely go together.. Quick Google search and you'll see that people need to slightly adjust it at time in order for it to work depending on the browsers etc. It should work in all MODERN browsers but it may not work always work https://learnwebtutorials.com/why-javascript-location-reload-does-not-work

Comment: "It will work everywhere the rest of the CRM works", Ie not on your 15 years old Internet Explorer etc. :-) Jokes aside, this is a hack, not a complete solution. It may need various adjustments. The thing is that using this approach (and knowing that you can send javascript through a simple echo from your logic hook to the browser and it will be executed, you can accomplish a lot of things that isn't easily done in SuiteCRM.

Comment: Did you read the article? then keep your passive aggressive "your 15 year old IE" browser to yourself. Another know-it-all that deals in absolutes..

Comment: Dear Robert, you probably didn't show I am joking. Please, calm down. I said from the first moment it's a hack.

Comment: Also, there are thousands of commands that are "not working" as advertised in various situations, but here you didn't ask how to deal with these. Here you asked how to reload a field or something in SuiteCRM and I came with a very simple approach, which can be built upon. The useful bit here, as I am writing above, is that you can "echo" javascript to your browser panel. 
The standard js way to reload a page -thus reloading your fields also- is location.reload(). This doesn't make me a "know it all" I think... and only a Sith deals with absolutes! :-)

Comment: Finally, this article doesn't say anything useful, I don't understand why you insist on it. If you have a problem with a cached page, is a problem with caching, something entirely different, not with the location.reload() command.